# Export tables in csv format with custom values using handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want to export the table by replacing some values in the cells.I am sharing the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arjunjayaraj/xy99an6n/1/) link for export in handsonTable

```
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"></div>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var temp = {"A1":"first","A2":"second","B1":"third","B2":"fourth"};
  var example1 = document.getElementById('example1');

  var hot = new Handsontable(example1, {
    data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(2, 2),
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true
  });

  var buttons = {

    file: document.getElementById('export-file')
  };

  var exportPlugin = hot.getPlugin('exportFile');


  buttons.file.addEventListener('click', function() {
    exportPlugin.downloadFile('csv', {filename: 'MyFile'});
  });



});

</style><!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue -->

<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.6.0/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.6.0/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
```

In the result table the cells will be having values A1,A2,B1,B2. I want to replace these values with the corresponding values in temp object

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got support from HandsonTable forum. They confirmed that there no way we can do this with the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Extend your `addEventListener` handler:

```
buttons.file.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var hiddenEl = document.getElementById('example1hidden');
  var tmpHot = new Handsontable(hiddenEl, {
    data: hot.getData(),
  });
  fixValues(tmpHot, temp);
  var exportPlgn = tmpHot.getPlugin('exportFile'); 
  exportPlgn.downloadFile('csv', {filename: 'MyFile'});
  tmpHot.destroy();
});

function fixValues(hTable, values){
  var d = hTable.getData();
  for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i ++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < d[i].length; j ++) {
      var key = hTable.getDataAtCell(i, j);
      if(values[key]) {
        hTable.setDataAtCell(i, j, values[key], 'customUpdate');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xy99an6n/18/)